# JavaScript assignment

Tags: javascript

can you explain how did this assignment is work,

var fe, f = document.forms[0], h;

which one equal to which one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Above is equivalent to

```
var fe;
var f = document.forms[0];
var h;
```

Basically, the 'comma' ends one declaration and starts another. fe and h would be undefined after the above statement whereas f will be set to first form in the document.

Comment: Thanks CMS, I corrected my post. My C# and JS knowledge gets me confused!

Comment: You're welcome SolutionYogi, and you're not alone!, that also happens to me sometimes...